# Caph-list not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I am using Angular.JS with tizen to create a smart tv app. I want to get a list of subtitles to show on my video app but I keep getting this error: "Error: The caph-list's container and template view should have their own size such as width and height."

On my main html I have a "settings" directive here:
`<settings></settings>`

that uses settings.html to display a caph-list here:
`<caph-list container-class="container" wrapper-class="setting-wrapper" items="item in subtitles"> <div class="item" focusable>{{item}}</div>  </caph-list>`

I've tried various setups with the container and wrappers such as this within my settings.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <caph-list container-class="container" wrapper-class="setting-wrapper" items="item in 
subtitles">
<div class="item" focusable>{{item}}</div> 
        </caph-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I still am getting the same error.

Here is the CSS being used on the container and wrapper classes:

```
.container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.setting-wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}
.item {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Here is the subtitles array at the start:

```
$scope.subtitles = ["1","2","3"]
```

This array will change to an array of objects containing subtitle information when a video is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Your container has 0 px width, probably. Try setting an absolute value instead of percentage, i.e, 800 px instead of 60%), and make sure that the parent element has a width and height (not 0.)

Comment: Even after that there I still get the same error. What's odd is that the error shows up when the array I'm setting to it gets populated. I should also note the array starts empty and gets populated later.

Comment: Did you try to create the caph-list after populating your array?

Comment: The caph list is empty at first along with the array it is attached too and the array will get populated later on.

Comment: Caph-list is being created by calculating the items' and container's dimensions. It cannot be created with an empty arrray, so you must be sure that the array is populated before creating the caph-list.

Comment: Ok so the I added values to the array from the start and the error is still showing up.

Comment: Updated. Does the CONSTANT object need to be updated too?

Comment: The items class is actually the item class. Just a typo fixed now.

Comment: Can you try this please, set the width of the container to a fixed value, i.e, 300px, instead of 60%. Then try creating the caph-list using the array subtitles with values ["1","2","3"]

Comment: So I changed the CSS above once more to add fixed values. Now the same error pops up at the time the app is launched.

Comment: Please post the code where you create the caph-list.

Comment: That is in the HTML above.

Comment: No, I meant the JavaScript code where you populate the array. Please see this example:
https://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/tv/caphdocs/main.html?type=angular&doc=demo&p1=1

Comment: After some messing around I found some html elements that were misplaced which fixed my issue. Thanks for the help guys!